# A finite group of isometries is isomorphic to a subgroup of $SO(3)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, finite-groups

I want to show that the rotation group of a polyhedron is isomorphic to a finite subgroup of $SO(3)$, since then I can use the classification of those subgroups to classify all polyhedral rotation groups.

Since a polyhedron has finitely many faces, edges, and vertices, its rotation group (defined as the group of rotations about some line that send the polyhedron to itself) is finite. I would like to show that there is a point through which all rotation axes pass. If we then let that point be the origin, the rotation group will be a finite subgroup of $SO(3)$. But why can't there be two or three rotations, whose axes are not concurrent? Would this contradict the group being finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center of gravity (or simply the arithmetic mean of the vertices) is an invariant.

Comment: Can you remind me why? Is the arithmetic mean of the vertices the unique point that minimizes the sum of squared distances from each vertex?